# Protect from theft at flash level

Tags: security, anti-theft

There are a lot of apps that could block your phone in case of theft, take picture of thief remotely and such, but in case of reset any of this *security* methods will be useless

So I was wondering if there is such thing but at a flash level, shielded from simple ereases? An advanced user only could bypass this settings by re flashing. But regular thief could still be detected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that sort of protection is available for Samsung devices: [LoJack Device Compatibility](https://lojack.absolute.com/en/confirmdevice)

Explanation of what LoJack does:

> LoJack will be embedded in the Galaxy S4's firmware layer, where it
>   remains dormant until you awaken it with a monthly subscription that
>   becomes your theft insurance. This firmware situation is key -- even
>   if robbers wipe your phone to the factory settings, LoJack is still
>   active, and unremovable. [-- CNET Article](http://www.cnet.com/news/lojack-for-samsung-galaxy-s4-goes-hard-core-on-thieves/)

It's difficult to find technical explanations for this software, but from how I understand it, LoJack is installed as an invisible system app, but a copy of it is also kept in the BIOS (pre-bootloader), and is re-installed to any ROM that is flashed. The app is what sends location, signed-in accounts, pictures via standard cell/WiFi protocols. LoJack guarantees to find the thief within 30 days or they send you a new device.

As of late 2015, there is also another type of security introduced with Android Lollipop/Marshmallow called FRP, which forces you to sign in with the previous Google account when you flash a new ROM. But this is hardly a security feature since it [has been bypassed](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/02/rootjunky-shows-off-just-how-easy-it-is-to-bypass-the-factory-reset-protection-on-samsung-phones-due-to-a-flaw-in-their-software/), but it is still a good step forward for Android.